# Is there an "lseek" to memmove?

Tags: c, linux, unix, memcpy, memmove

I have a buffer with n bytes, but I only want read in sizeof(something) bytes from byte 3, meaning I don't want to read in byte 1 and 2 from the buffer. For example...

For some buffer, byte 1 = 'a', byte 2 = 'b', byte 3 = uint64_t variable. What I want to do is something like

```
1. set begin to byte 3
2. read in sizeof(uint64_t) bytes from buffer using memmove
```

Comment: Is the pointer math and casting too hard for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a bit of clarification.  C array indexing starts at 0, not 1, so it's more accurate to say that byte 0 is `'a'` and byte 1 is `'b'`.  Second, your third byte, cannot contain a `uint64_t` variable, but index 2 may well be the *beginning* of a `uint64_t` object.

No, there is no `lseek` equivalent for `memmove()` -- because, unlike file operations, a call to `memmove()` must specify the starting point.

And in this case, you might as well use `memcpy()` rather than `memmove()`.  The only difference between them is that `memmove()` handles overlapping buffers correctly.  Since your source and target are distinct objects, that's not a concern.  It's not going to significantly affect your code's speed, but anyone reading it won't have to wonder why you chose to use `memmove()`.

Given:

```
unsigned char buf[SOME_SIZE];
uint64_t target;
```

you can do something like this:

```
memcpy(&target, buf+2, sizeof target);
```

Note that I used `sizeof target` rather than `sizeof (uint64_t)`.  Either will work, but using `sizeof target` makes your code more resilient (less vulnerable to errors as you change it later on).  If you decide to change the type of `target`, you don't need to remember to change the type in the `memcpy()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use this:

```
uint64_t num;
num = * ((uint64_t *) (buffer + 2))
```

Comment: Because it can fail if that address is misaligned.

Comment: Right. Okay, you better use `memcpy` of some sort then, but I see you already made a nice answer explaining that :)